# How do I select the top ten scores in a database table full of scores using linq in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I'm new to Linq and database programming in general, I could really use some help.

I have tried using

```
var TopTen =  from t in datacontext.Scores.Take(10)
              orderby t.LifetimeScore descending
              select t;
```

but this only seems to give me the first ten entries in the DB not the top ten. I know I need to order the table before the search but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7):

You have to take 10 from the result, not before:

```
var TopTen = (from t in datacontext.Scores 
              orderby t.LifetimeScore descending 
              select t).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var TopTen =  datacontext.Scores.OrderByDescending(t => LifetimeScore ).Take(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to LINQ myself but here's what I think should work:

```
var TopTen =  (from t in datacontext.Scores
              orderby t.LifetimeScore descending
              select t).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var TopTen =  from t in datacontext.Scores
              orderby t.LifetimeScore descending
              select t;
TopTen = TopTen.Take(10).ToArray();
```

Last statement will make sure the query is **executed**.